# How can I add single field to firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In order to save user credentials I use Firestore. In my app, I put an image picker only in the profile screen not in the authentication screen. I want the user to pick an image and upload it to Firebase storage after authenticating. Then the URL of the image taken from Firebase storage should be in Firestore. [image: It is Firestore image after authentication]

How can I add a single 'photoUrl' key field and value after authentication? I want a patch request. It only adds the desired field.

[image: I want to get this one]

I saw the update method, but it update the whole JSON data.

Comment: can you show your current code of the update function ?

Comment: Did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data? If you can't get that to work, can you show us the code of what you tried?

Comment: create map add  field with key value that field  you want update in  
firebase then call firebase method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I saw the update method, but it update the whole JSON data.

It sounds to me that you have used the [set()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/set.html) function which:

> Sets data on the document, **overwriting** any existing data.

However, if you have passed a [SetOptions](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/5.15.2/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/SetOptions-class.html) object as an argument, then:

> If SetOptions are provided, the data can be merged into an existing document instead of overwriting.

If you need to simply update a document, you have to create an object of type `Map<Object, Object?>` and pass it to the [update](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/update.html) function.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to know the document ID of the user and update the value with the update method of FirebaseFirestore.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("collectionName").doc("documentId").update({"photoUrl": "actualUrl"});
```